# Return Array position of lowest number (not negative)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to return the position of the element closest to zero without being a negative number.

I have 4 roll sizes(in") to cut film from. I'm trying to enter a width variable and subtract from the elements of the array and the closest to 0 will return the array position of the best roll size.  I hope this makes sense.  Thanks.

```
  var width = ""

var rollArray = [36, 48, 60, 72]
            var newArray = []
            for(i in rollArray){ newArray.push ((rollArray[i]) - width) }

alert(newArray);
```

returns width minus each element, now I need to find how to return the lowest values array position so that I can get the roll size from the equivalent rollArray position.

Comment: Note as a matter of proper practice, don't use `for-in` for iterating an array in JavaScript. It's purpose is iterating over object properties. Instead do `for (var i=0; i<rollArray.length; i++)`  If any props or methods get added to the Array prototype, you'll get odd results from the `for-in`.

Comment: So using your example, what did you want returned? 0 since 36 is the closest to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var width = 41;
var rollArray = [36, 48, 60, 72];
var closest = rollArray.filter(function(ele){return ele-width >= 0}).sort()[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var width = ""

var rollArray = [36, 48, 60, 72]
            var newArray = []
            var min=1000000 //a very large number that you know it's larger than (rollArray[i]) - width)
            var minIndex=-1
            for (var i=0; i<rollArray.length; i++){ newArray.push ((rollArray[i]) - width) 
            if (min< rollArray[i]) - width &  rollArray[i]) - width >0)
            {
                            min = rollArray[i]) - width;
                            minIndex = i;
            }
}
alert (minIndex);
alert(newArray);
```

Comment: there are easier ways than that. But it is an interesting approach

Answer (score 0):

```
var width = 37;
var rollArray = [36, 48, 60, 72];
var closest = null;
for (var i=0; i<rollArray.length; i++)
{
    if (rollArray[i] >= width)
    {
        if (closest == null || rollArray[i] <= rollArray[closest])
        {
            closest = i;
        }
    }
}
```